# @Controller is not being invoked for GET request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am attempting to use Spring 3 MVC support for annotated controllers in my web application.
my configuration is as follows:

**1- web.xml:**

```
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/springmvc/*</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

**2- applicationContext.xml:** my webpages are under webapp folder directly

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
```

**3- Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test.jsp")
public class Test{

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get() {
        System.out.println("######## GET METHOD FOR test.jsp ########");
        return "test.jsp";
    }

}
```

NOTE: i am loading the **applicationContext** in a **ServletContextListener** as follows:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    "classpath:spring/config/applicationContext.xml");
```

please advise how to solve this issue, thanks.

also i have another question that if it's possible to make the dispatcher servlet dispatches specific jsp pages not all the pages in the application, since not all my jsp pages have controllers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dispatcher servlet name in web.xml is `dispatcher`. Spring tries to load dispatcher-servlet.xml in this case (`servlet_name-servlet.xml`). Whereas you have defined your spring configuration in `applicationContext.xml`. Rename it to `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

Or you can also ask Spring to read applicationContext by setting init-param in servlet. For example:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/springmvc/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Regarding your second question, you can use spring's `view-controller` mapping to directly render view.

```
<mvc:view-controller path="demo/flot" view-name="demo/flot"/>
```

Read: [17.15.5 Configuring View Controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: followed your note, and still have the same issue, can this be related to the way i am loading applicationContext (please take look at edited question) ? also can this be related to the return string for the get method ? please advise.

Comment: You need to check if spring configuration is loaded by looking into logs. Also as mentioned by @tesla1984 change the return string to "test" instead of "test.jsp"

Answer (score 1):

change `return "test.jsp"` to `return test`. your return string will add the `prefix` and `suffix`

Answer (score 0):

solved as follows:

```
<listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
             classpath:spring/config/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>    
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/config/dispatcherServlet.xml</param-value>
       </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern>/myapp/*</url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
```